# Why is turbine inlet temperature called "TET"?

Tags: jet-engine, terminology, turbine

I assume that at some point giggling engineering students caused their instructor to change "turbine inlet temperature" from TIT to TET, but I wonder if anyone knows the *real* reason and history? Perhaps adapted from another language?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The temperature in jet engine turbines is usually measured in one (or more) of these places:

- Behind the combustion chamber at the turbine inlet: [Turbine Inlet Temperature (TIT)](https://www.skybrary.aero/index.php/Turbine_Inlet_Temperature_(TIT))
- Between low and high pressure turbine: [Interstage Turbine Temperature (ITT)](https://www.skybrary.aero/index.php/Interstage_Turbine_Temperature_(ITT))
- Behind the last turbine stage: [EGT (Exhaust Gas Temperature)](https://www.skybrary.aero/index.php/Exhaust_Gas_Temperature_(EGT)) or TOT (Turbine Outlet Temperature)

As far as I know, **TET** is not used as an acronym for Turbine Inlet Temperature, where **TIT** is used.

There are however two different definitions for TET:

1. In gas turbines for power plants, TET stands for **Turbine Entry Temperature** and is defined in ISO 11086:1996 (Gas Turbines - Vocabulary).

   > It is very important for gas turbine calculations how the temperatures
   > in the hot part of the gas turbine are defined:
   >
   > - **TIT - Turbine inlet temperature** is defined as the temperature that would occur before the nozzle guide vanes, if all cooling air was
   >   mixed into the flue gases at that point.
   > - **TRIT - Turbine rotor inlet temperature** is the temperature before the first rotor stage, i.e. right before the work extraction
   >   begins.
   > - **TET - Turbine entry temperature** is the actual temperature before the nozzle guide vanes.

   <sup>([Gas Turbine Cooling Modeling - Thermodynamic Analysis and Cycle Simulations](https://www.osti.gov/etdeweb/servlets/purl/335513) by Kristin Jordal)</sup>
2. TET is also sometimes defined as **Turbine Exit Temperature**, e.g. in [this paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S2352484719311254) (also for power plant gas turbines) or in [this patent](https://patents.google.com/patent/US4060979) (for a jet engine):

   > We have found that the turbine inlet temperature (TIT) or turbine exit temperature (TET) are viable parameters for indicating stall [...]

To avoid confusion, always check the glossary of the document when encountering TET. If there is no definition, it might be difficult to tell what the author meant.

Comment: Ahhh, excellent post. My confusion is from a 1970s article by the Olympus team that refers to TET without defining it - when I googled the term the resulting article was on TIT. I did not notice the fine print.

Comment: The turbine *inlet* temperature is pretty much fixed, unless you have a flame-out, since the combustion temperature depends mainly on chemistry, not aerodynamics.  On the other hand the *exit* temperature depends strongly on the mass flow through the turbine and the power it is producing, so it is a much more useful measure of "what the engine is doing" (not to mention that it is lower than the inlet temperature, and therefore easier to measure).

Comment: Please note that the TIT cannot be measured as it is generally too high for cooled turbine engines. Also, the SOT is sometimes referenced, the Stator Outlet Temperature, i.e. the temperature behind the nozzle guide vanes.